# Mac Air -first no sound, now it won't charge

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, charging, power

First the sound went out on my macbook air.  I was in the airport and tried everything I knew, nothing worked.  Then I went to plug into an outlet I found, and realized it wasn't charging.  It does supply enough power to use the laptop, but there is no light on the maglite charger.  I tried SMC reset (pram as well), heating up the maglite unit, and a few other random things.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Opened up the laptop, and a wire was lose right by the fan. That seemed to be the charging issue.  Another wire was lose on the other side, may have been audio.  Everything works great now!

Prob bumped the air a little too harshly.